# Automatic insertion of a new row

Tags: openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I am looking for a solution in Libre/OpenOffice Calc, to automatically insert a new row if all the fields of the current row are filled with data.

A bit more detailed: 
There is a spreadsheet in which the monthly expenses are stored, and at the end of each month a summary is generated and included under the last row of the month. The amount of data (number of lines) for a given month is unknown and thus not fix. A solution would be nice, that would allow to enter the data and at the end of the row a new row would be automatically inserted between the actual row and the row of the monthly summary.
I hope it was somewhat clear.

Answer (score -1):

many reasons make me feel you should prefere some other storage (database?). Once this move is done, you can  connect calc to the db.
Same eye effect with a much cleaner and safer work.

hope will help

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I prefer to use a single calc file in a dropbox folder to have access from everywhere on different platforms. I am afraid using a database would make it more complicated and would reduce the portability.

Comment: Sure, makes sense to me. Better than anyone else, you know when you reach the end of a spreadsheet capabilities.